# Changing row values in R

Tags: r

I am running the following code:

```
data<-cbind(c(rep(1,2),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),c(rep(1:3,3),1),c("A",
                      "B","A",rep("B",2),"A","A","B","A","A"))
data<-data.frame(data)
colnames(data)<-c("sub","days","cat") ## Changing col names
work<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(data$sub)) {
sand<-subset(data,sub==i)
for (j in 1:length(sand$cat)) {
ifelse(sand$cat[j]=="B",sand$cat[j+1]=="B","A")
}
work<-rbind(work,sand)
}

> work
   sub days cat
1    1    1   A
2    1    2   B
3    2    3   A
4    2    1   B
5    2    2   B
6    2    3   A
7    3    1   A
8    3    2   B
9    3    3   A
10   3    1   A
```

Not something I want. When I run ifelse part, what I want is the moment it touches B, the remaining values of the subset return B as well. Row 6, 9 and 10 should give me B instead of A (since under sub==2, cat=="B" in row 5, so I should get cat="B" in row 6 as it is still sub=2).

Hope you understand the question. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your sample data, I might run

```
cat2<-with(data, levels(cat)[ave(as.numeric(cat), sub, FUN=cummax)])
```

which would give

```
cbind(data, cat2)
#    sub days cat cat2
# 1    1    1   A    A
# 2    1    2   B    B
# 3    2    3   A    A
# 4    2    1   B    B
# 5    2    2   B    B
# 6    2    3   A    B
# 7    3    1   A    A
# 8    3    2   B    B
# 9    3    3   A    B
# 10   3    1   A    B
```

I use `ave` to work in groups defined by `sub`, then I use `cummax` to find the highest factor level seen for each subset at each point (which will be B when it's seen). I had to do some fooling around because `cummax` only works with numeric vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want... A few minor changes to your code should do the trick:
1) Only go up to the number of unique 'sub' values (line 6 - the 'i' loop): you don't need to go through every row in the table; only the unique values of 'sub'
2) Only go up to the second-to-last 'cat' line within the subset (line 8 - the 'j' loop): you are wanting to change the next value based on a previous value so can stop at the second-to-last row
3) Don't change the next row value to 'A' if it's not 'B' (line 9): this was the fundamental problem. If you changed the next value to 'A' then the next loop would see it as an 'A' even if it was a 'B'

The complete code is:

```
data<-cbind(c(rep(1,2),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),c(rep(1:3,3),1),c("A",
                      "B","A",rep("B",2),"A","A","B","A","A"))
data<-data.frame(data)
colnames(data)<-c("sub","days","cat") ## Changing col names
work<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(unique(data$sub))) {
    sand<-subset(data,sub==i)
    for (j in 1:(length(sand$cat)-1)) {
        if(sand$cat[j]=="B")
            sand$cat[j+1] = "B"
    }
    work<-rbind(work,sand)
}

>work
   sub days cat
1    1    1   A
2    1    2   B
3    2    3   A
4    2    1   B
5    2    2   B
6    2    3   B
7    3    1   A
8    3    2   B
9    3    3   B
10   3    1   B
```

Does that do what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. Thank you for the help and explanation

Comment: No problem though the solution by MrFlick is more elegant! +1 MrFlick.